# Absolute positioned div does not show outside the relative positioned div

Tags: html, css, css-position

Please look at the following example

http://jsfiddle.net/GANeX/90/

I want to show my **green colored div** outside the `wrapper`. I cannot change the positioning of the `wrapper` div as `inner-wrapper` also holds some other content which may come out when we change the `position:relative` to `position:static`.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you remove the `overflow` properties it will show up... but you have the `overflow` for a reason, right? http://jsfiddle.net/GANeX/91/

Comment: and you also really need this div inside th others?

Comment: Yes, because there are many such green divs related to other data

Comment: @JayantVarshney, and what are you expecting to see? the green div outsite the parent and covering the browser scrolling buttons?

Comment: @skip405: yes... but cannot put `content-wrapper` outside `wrapper`.. any other method of doing this and keeping the hierarchy same

Comment: @JoelWorsham, technically it can... the absolute positioning works quite unexpectedly sometimes )) Consider having a look at an example (http://jsfiddle.net/JP8dJ/) where the absolutely positioned div is not hidden though it is a direct child of the block with `overflow: hidden;` This is the closest solution to the problem of the question, imo

Comment: @JayantVarshney, the closest you can get is this - http://jsfiddle.net/GANeX/98/ - but your yellow div is positioned relatively too

Comment: @Joel Worsham, my jaw dropped when I saw that for the first time too )) But looking at this later - everything seems to be logical :)

Comment: Thanks guys. I had to made to certain changes to make this work out. I changed the `position:fixed` and updated **x** and **y** locations. This works fine for me. Changes are http://jsfiddle.net/GANeX/99/

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the things you don't want to overflow in an element with a class called `dont-overflow`. Set the `width` of that class to the current `.wrapper` width, and then remove the overflow from the parent and add it to that class:

CSS `dont-overflow` class:

```
.dont-overflow
{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='inner-wrapper'>
         <div class='content-wrapper'></div>
         <div class='dont-overflow'>
             <div class='content-wrapper'></div>
             <div class='content-wrapper'></div>
             <div class='content-wrapper'></div>
         </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GANeX/97/

Comment: Thanks Alex! but.. Need overflow over wrapper.. :P

Comment: @JayantVarshney Can you explain the need for overflow? What you are asking is impossible if you can't change any of your CSS or HTML

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use z-index.

```
.inner-wrapper{
position:absolute;
left:10px;
right:10px;
top:5px;
bottom:5px;
z-index: 999;
background:yellow;}
```